# Finding the nearest numeric match in a database with two variables

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation

I'm trying to find the closest places nearby an user.

**1. Provided information**

I got the user Lat & Lon values. This values represents the user location.

```
Lat = user latitude. **Example: 31.728453**
Lon = user longitude. **Example: 37.53922**

**Database Example**
Place name  | Lat      | Lon
Pizza place | 31.23232 | 36.94933
Candy shop  | 2.4943   | -232.3393
Bakery      | 40.32932 | 25.34343
```

**2. Looking for the closest records - The problem**

I'm trying to figure out how I can query to retrieve the closest places nearby the user, using the above provided information (lat&lon values).
For the above example, the most nearby place will be "**Pizza Place**" because it's the closest place to the user location.
I am using SQL & PHP I can't think of a solution for getting the top 5 closest places to the user. Hope you can help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: show what you have done in SQL and PHP

Comment: I'm no expert on the details, but you want to look in to MySQL's Spatial Indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Sql-ish :

```
select the 5 first places
from your database 
ordered by ascending distance to the current location
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I'm looking for. the "distance" contains lat & lon values as shown above..

Answer (score 0):

May be this?

```
WHERE lat between @lat and @lon or lon between @lat and @lon
```

where @lan and @lon are variables

Comment: That's really nothing like how latitude and longitude work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that here it is important to know what technology stack you are using. For example, as you say you are using SQL, there are some technologies like [Oracle Spatial](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Spatial) or [Postgis](http://postgis.net/) that will allow you to get the distance between two points when you manage the info in the right way. In your case, mySql may not be the best, but still it has its [spatial extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html). There is a good article out there about ["Using the new spatial functions in MySQL 5.6 for geo-enabled applications"](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/), look for the `st_distance` function.

So instead of lat/long real numbers you would be using geometry objects in a specific projection, for example [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) in this case.

Once you get the distance, you could get top 5.

If you have a lot of data, you may not want to calculate the distance to every single point in the database, but first query for a bounding box rectangle, and then calculate the distance for a few points.

Please note that you can't apply here a normal [Cartesian distance](http://math.info/Algebra/Distance_Cartesian_Plane/), as we are not in a Cartesian system.

Comment: As tagged above, I use mysql and after reading the new spatial functions in MySQL 5.6, I might need to upgrade my MySQL version to from 5.5 to 5.6 and learn more about this functions. It is still little unclear how I can use this functions to get nearby locations from my database, so if you can give me some hints i'll find it helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to upgrade to at least version 5.6, as that will enable you to use those functions. Once that you do that, the idea is to calculate the distance and get the 5 points with the lowest value. How many points would you have in your table? If they are not many that could be enough. Otherwise you may have to add a bounding box filter first for performance.

Comment: Honestly I don´t have a good testing environment here (it´s Sunday, I work mostly with Oracle and PostGis, except for a db with MySql 5.5). But it should be as simple as (note there will be syntax errors) having a Geometry field value in your table, and send the point as a parameter : `select id, st_distance(point(@lon, @lat), geom) from my_table order by 2`

Comment: If there is no option that you can upgrade to 5.6, another option is to use the Haversine Formula [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and any implementation for MySql [link](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/stored-function-haversine-distance-computation/) but if you are going to work with spatial functionalities why wouldn't you use the built in ones, instead of implementing them yourself.

Comment: Currently, I implemented the Harversine Formula and im working with it until I will be able to upgrade to 5.6. Thank you.

Comment: Hopefully "Haversine" formula (please note the right spelling) will be good enough for you. If after a while my answer turns out to be useful, feel free to accept it or at least upvote. Thanks.